# Javascript instantiate with arguments

Tags: javascript

I know this is a pure javascript basics error which I am getting wrong. I am trying to wrap my `createError` function like this:

```
export const throwError = error => {
  return createError(error, {
    message: 'This is my error'
  });
}
```

And then:

```
throw new (throwError ('Error')); // #1 This works

throw new throwError ('Error'); // #2 This doesn't work without paranthesis
```

How can I have it work without including `()`. Why it doesn't work? Is it possible to `return new createError..` inside my `throwError` function (not working)?

Comment: In your code are you calling the `throw new....` lines back to back like that? Once you throw the first error, the second one won't be thrown.

Comment: `new throwError (args)` means that `throwError` is the name of a class. But `throwError` isn't a class constructor.

Comment: `createError()` returns a class constructor, you need the parentheses to make the returned value be used as the constructor, instead of just `throwError`.

Comment: @KhauriMcClain I think they're just trying each syntax in the same place, one works, the other doesn't.

Comment: @KhauriMcClain not back to back, try each at a time

Comment: @Barmar so how do I improve my throwError function to return the class constructor that createError is returning?

Comment: I want to use it as in #2. so how do I change my throwError function to handle that?

Comment: do i make my throwError a class instead? how will i return createError() from that class to be able to use it without paranthesis?

Comment: This is kind of an unusual case. It's not common to have functions that return constructors. The language doesn't really provide a simplified syntax.

Comment: @Barmar just did `return new (createError())` and it worked :)

Comment: and use it like `throw throwError()`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be doing

```
export const MyError = createError('Error', {
  message: 'This is my error'
});
```

```
throw new MyError(); // parenthesis optional here
```

---

If you really need to pass the `Error` argument dynamically (which isn't good for performance, as it creates lots of different classes) you cannot really avoid the parenthesis around the call that creates the constructor. Written more explicitly, it works like this:

```
throw new (throwError('Error'))(); // equivalent to:
```

```
const error = throwError('Error');
throw new error();
```